# Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, sql-server-ce

I've checked other answers but nothing seems to work. I continuously get this error on my (new) Windows 10 machine running Visual Studio Community 2017. I've tried just about everything and now I'm thinking it has something to do with running on a Windows 10 machine as I copied the same code from my Windows 8.1 machine in which I had no issue at all with SQL Server CE 4.0.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling SQL Server Compact 4.0, reinstalling the **System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0** package, removing and re-adding the assembly...I'm at a lost as I've spent a good part of five hours trying to compile.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you using your CE file, it's an sdf file.

Comment: Have you installed the 4.0 MSI?

Comment: What application is throwing this error? One you are writing? SQL Server CE is an in-process database; it typically comes bundled in an application and is not something you install in your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I didn't try *everything* as I previously mentioned as I dug through some more suggestions and it turns out I was missing Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 which I downloaded and seems to have fixed the problem.

For those that stumble onto my question and answer, it can be downloaded here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

And thank you to whom responded to my post with their comments and suggestions. I believe [ErikEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) provided the correct response.